# Count number of elements in column declared as varray of a table

Tags: database, oracle, plsql

Given the following table

```
TYPE MYTYPE IS VARRAY(100) OF NUMBER;
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEES(ID NUMBER(*), SALARY_HISTORY(MYTYPE) );
```

How can i count the number of elements in the SALARY_HISTORY column in order to list in that column all the salaries that an employee had ?

Comment: if you just want to count how many records in the table it is just employees.count as per the oracle documentation https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/collections.htm

Answer (score 1):

See the query at the bottom of the demonstration below. I used your code, but named the table `E` since I already have a table `EMPLOYEES`. Note that SQL is not PL/SQL; to use your type in SQL, you must use the `CREATE TYPE` statement.

```
create TYPE MYTYPE IS VARRAY(100) OF NUMBER;
/

CREATE TABLE E(ID NUMBER, SALARY_HISTORY MYTYPE );

insert into e values (1, mytype(1, 2, 3));
insert into e values (3, mytype(33, 22, 0, 33, 0));

select * from e;

ID  SALARY_HISTORY
--  ------------------------------
 1  INTRO.MYTYPE(1, 2, 3)
 3  INTRO.MYTYPE(33, 22, 0, 33, 0)

select id, count(*)
from e, table(e.salary_history)
group by id;

   ID   COUNT(*)
----- ----------
    1          3
    3          5
```

Or, perhaps (if that's what you need):  - `column_value` is the name of the column produced by the `table` operator.

```
select   id, count(distinct column_value) as distinct_cnt
from     e, table(e.salary_history)
group by id;

   ID DISTINCT_CNT
----- ------------
    1            3
    3            3
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert your data model to regular relational tables if possible.  About half of all programmers know how to use SQL.  Probably less than 0.01% of them know how to query a VARRAY.  What's the point of a database if nobody knows how to query it?  And what are you going to do when you need to add a date column to the history information, or run into performance problems?

If you must use object-relational columns a nested table makes things a bit simpler and avoids limiting the number of elements.

```
create or replace type mytype is table of number;

create table employees(id number(*), salary_history mytype)
   nested table salary_history store as employees_salary_history;

insert into employees values(null, null);
insert into employees values(0, mytype());
insert into employees values(1, mytype(1));
insert into employees values(2, mytype(1,2));
insert into employees values(3, mytype(1,2,3));

select id, nvl(cardinality(salary_history), 0) salary_count
from employees;

ID   SALARY_COUNT
--   ------------
                0
 0              0
 1              1
 2              2
 3              3
```

If you're stuck with your current data model then Mathguy's answer should work, although the cross join may cause performance issues.